# Redmine Project.rebuild gave segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

On Redmine 1.4 I had problems with `lft` and `rgt` values on `projects` table, so projects default list doesn't work well.
I read about to rebuild `lft` and `rgt` field of project table, with this steps:

1. reset all values of `lft` and `rgt` with `0`
2. call this command: `ruby script/runner -e production 'Project.rebuild!'` from redmine home

Unfortunately this last command doesn't work and give me `Segmentation fault`.
How can I make correctly this rebuild?

This is log text of segmentation fault:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route.rb:160: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0029 p:---- s:0107 b:0107 l:000106 d:000106 CFUNC  :instance_eval
c:0028 p:0107 s:0102 b:0102 l:000101 d:000101 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route.rb:160
c:0027 p:0022 s:0095 b:0095 l:000094 d:000094 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route.rb:117
c:0026 p:0235 s:0092 b:0092 l:000091 d:000091 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/builder.rb:178
c:0025 p:0036 s:0081 b:0081 l:000080 d:000080 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:310
c:0024 p:0021 s:0075 b:0075 l:000074 d:000074 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:19
c:0023 p:1705 s:0070 b:0070 l:0015f8 d:001650 BLOCK  /usr/share/redmine/config/routes.rb:318
c:0022 p:0021 s:0067 b:0067 l:000066 d:000066 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:227
c:0021 p:0019 s:0064 b:0064 l:0015f8 d:0015f8 TOP    /usr/share/redmine/config/routes.rb:1
c:0020 p:---- s:0062 b:0062 l:000061 d:000061 FINISH
c:0019 p:---- s:0060 b:0060 l:000059 d:000059 CFUNC  :load
c:0018 p:0056 s:0056 b:0056 l:000055 d:000055 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:173
c:0017 p:0012 s:0050 b:0050 l:000041 d:000049 BLOCK  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:287
c:0016 p:---- s:0047 b:0047 l:000046 d:000046 FINISH
c:0015 p:---- s:0045 b:0045 l:000044 d:000044 CFUNC  :each
c:0014 p:0034 s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:287
c:0013 p:0038 s:0039 b:0039 l:000038 d:000038 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:267
c:0012 p:0125 s:0036 b:0036 l:000035 d:000035 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:537
c:0011 p:0381 s:0033 b:0033 l:000032 d:000032 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:188
c:0010 p:0063 s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 METHOD /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113
c:0009 p:0192 s:0024 b:0024 l:000023 d:000023 TOP    /usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb:21
c:0008 p:---- s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 CFUNC  :require
c:0006 p:0166 s:0016 b:0016 l:001778 d:001778 TOP    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/commands/runner.rb:39
c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :require
c:0003 p:0038 s:0006 b:0006 l:000178 d:001088 EVAL   script/runner:3
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000178 d:000178 TOP

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
script/runner:3:in `<main>'
script/runner:3:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/commands/runner.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/commands/runner.rb:39:in `require'
/usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:188:in `process'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:537:in `initialize_routing'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:267:in `load!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:287:in `load_routes!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:287:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:287:in `block in load_routes!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:173:in `load_with_new_constant_marking'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:173:in `load'
/usr/share/redmine/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:227:in `draw'
/usr/share/redmine/config/routes.rb:318:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:19:in `connect'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:310:in `add_route'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/builder.rb:178:in `build'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route.rb:117:in `freeze'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route.rb:160:in `write_generation!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route.rb:160:in `instance_eval'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x155d69) [0x7f7b5bff6d69]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x576e9) [0x7f7b5bef86e9]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(rb_bug+0xb7) [0x7f7b5bef90d7]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0xf62cf) [0x7f7b5bf972cf]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x364a0) [0x7f7b5bb184a0]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b948) [0x7f7b5bf0c948]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b235) [0x7f7b5bf0c235]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6bc82) [0x7f7b5bf0cc82]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(st_foreach+0xbc) [0x7f7b5bf9f22c]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b459) [0x7f7b5bf0c459]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6bc56) [0x7f7b5bf0cc56]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(st_foreach+0xbc) [0x7f7b5bf9f22c]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b719) [0x7f7b5bf0c719]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6bc56) [0x7f7b5bf0cc56]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(st_foreach+0xbc) [0x7f7b5bf9f22c]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b719) [0x7f7b5bf0c719]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6bc56) [0x7f7b5bf0cc56]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(st_foreach+0xbc) [0x7f7b5bf9f22c]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b719) [0x7f7b5bf0c719]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b235) [0x7f7b5bf0c235]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6bc56) [0x7f7b5bf0cc56]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(st_foreach+0xbc) [0x7f7b5bf9f22c]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b719) [0x7f7b5bf0c719]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6bc56) [0x7f7b5bf0cc56]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(st_foreach+0xbc) [0x7f7b5bf9f22c]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b719) [0x7f7b5bf0c719]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b235) [0x7f7b5bf0c235]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6bc56) [0x7f7b5bf0cc56]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(st_foreach+0xbc) [0x7f7b5bf9f22c]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b719) [0x7f7b5bf0c719]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6bc56) [0x7f7b5bf0cc56]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(st_foreach+0xbc) [0x7f7b5bf9f22c]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b719) [0x7f7b5bf0c719]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6bc56) [0x7f7b5bf0cc56]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(st_foreach+0xbc) [0x7f7b5bf9f22c]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b719) [0x7f7b5bf0c719]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6bc56) [0x7f7b5bf0cc56]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(st_foreach+0xbc) [0x7f7b5bf9f22c]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b719) [0x7f7b5bf0c719]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6bc56) [0x7f7b5bf0cc56]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(st_foreach+0xbc) [0x7f7b5bf9f22c]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b719) [0x7f7b5bf0c719]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6bc56) [0x7f7b5bf0cc56]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(st_foreach+0xbc) [0x7f7b5bf9f22c]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6b719) [0x7f7b5bf0c719]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x6bc56) [0x7f7b5bf0cc56]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(st_foreach+0xbc) [0x7f7b5bf9f22c]
...
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x14b55d) [0x7f7b5bfec55d]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval+0x168) [0x7f7b5bff37f8]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x5dd35) [0x7f7b5befed35]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x5de98) [0x7f7b5befee98]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x14ebe1) [0x7f7b5bfefbe1]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x145b52) [0x7f7b5bfe6b52]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x14b55d) [0x7f7b5bfec55d]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(rb_yield+0x26e) [0x7f7b5bff215e]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(rb_ary_each+0x52) [0x7f7b5becbed2]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x14ebe1) [0x7f7b5bfefbe1]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x145b52) [0x7f7b5bfe6b52]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x14b55d) [0x7f7b5bfec55d]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval+0x168) [0x7f7b5bff37f8]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x5dd35) [0x7f7b5befed35]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(rb_require_safe+0x4ef) [0x7f7b5bf000ef]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x14ebe1) [0x7f7b5bfefbe1]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x145b52) [0x7f7b5bfe6b52]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x14b55d) [0x7f7b5bfec55d]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval+0x168) [0x7f7b5bff37f8]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x5dd35) [0x7f7b5befed35]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(rb_require_safe+0x4ef) [0x7f7b5bf000ef]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x14ebe1) [0x7f7b5bfefbe1]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x145b52) [0x7f7b5bfe6b52]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x14b55d) [0x7f7b5bfec55d]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval_main+0xaf) [0x7f7b5bff38df]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x5b0b2) [0x7f7b5befc0b2]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(ruby_exec_node+0x1d) [0x7f7b5befcb9d]
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(ruby_run_node+0x1e) [0x7f7b5befe74e]
ruby() [0x4007db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7f7b5bb0376d]
ruby() [0x400809]

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: script/runner

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
    2 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
    3 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb
    4 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb
    5 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    6 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb
    7 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
    8 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb
    9 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/psych.so
   10 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
   11 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/node.rb
   12 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/stream.rb
   13 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/document.rb
   14 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/sequence.rb
   15 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/scalar.rb
   16 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/mapping.rb
   17 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/alias.rb
   18 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes.rb
   19 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/streaming.rb
   20 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb
   21 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/strscan.so
   22 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/scalar_scanner.rb
   23 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb
   24 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/emitter.rb
   25 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb

   ---- CUT 8< -----

  881 /usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/extended_fields/lib/extended_custom_value_patch.rb
  882 /usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/extended_fields/lib/extended_query_custom_field_column.rb
  883 /usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/extended_fields/lib/extended_custom_query_patch.rb
  884 /usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/extended_fields/lib/extended_column.rb
  885 /usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/extended_fields/lib/extended_project_patch.rb
  886 /usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/extended_fields/lib/extended_user_patch.rb
  887 /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/extension.rb
  888 /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/extensions/sreg.rb
  889 /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/extensions/ax.rb
  890 /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/store/interface.rb
  891 /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/store/filesystem.rb
  892 /usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/open_id_authentication/lib/open_id_authentication/db_store.rb
  893 /usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/open_id_authentication/lib/open_id_authentication/mem_cache_store.rb
  894 /usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/open_id_authentication/lib/open_id_authentication/request.rb
  895 /usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/open_id_authentication/lib/open_id_authentication.rb
  896 /usr/share/redmine/app/models/time_entry.rb
  897 /usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/wiking/lib/wiking_formatter_patch.rb
  898 /usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/wiking/lib/wiking_wiki_helper_patch.rb
  899 /usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/wiking/lib/wiking_application_helper_patch.rb
  900 /usr/share/redmine/app/models/message_observer.rb
  901 /usr/share/redmine/app/models/board.rb
  902 /usr/share/redmine/app/models/message.rb
  903 /usr/share/redmine/app/models/issue_observer.rb
  904 /usr/share/redmine/app/models/journal_observer.rb
  905 /usr/share/redmine/app/models/news_observer.rb
  906 /usr/share/redmine/app/models/news.rb
  907 /usr/share/redmine/app/models/document_observer.rb
  908 /usr/share/redmine/app/models/wiki_content_observer.rb
  909 /usr/share/redmine/app/models/comment_observer.rb
  910 /usr/share/redmine/app/models/comment.rb
  911 /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/option_merger.rb

* Process memory map:

00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3767                               /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:02 3767                               /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:02 3767                               /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
015af000-0558a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f7b4c000000-7f7b4c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7b4c021000-7f7b50000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7b52454000-7f7b52455000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 533090                     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/sha2.so

   ---- CUT 8< -----

7f7b5b6c4000-7f7b5b8c3000 ---p 00007000 08:02 396161                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
7f7b5b8c3000-7f7b5b8c4000 r--p 00006000 08:02 396161                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
7f7b5b8c4000-7f7b5b8c5000 rw-p 00007000 08:02 396161                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
7f7b5b8c5000-7f7b5b8dd000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 396157                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f7b5b8dd000-7f7b5badc000 ---p 00018000 08:02 396157                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f7b5badc000-7f7b5badd000 r--p 00017000 08:02 396157                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f7b5badd000-7f7b5bade000 rw-p 00018000 08:02 396157                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f7b5bade000-7f7b5bae2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7b5bae2000-7f7b5bc97000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 395813                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f7b5bc97000-7f7b5be96000 ---p 001b5000 08:02 395813                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f7b5be96000-7f7b5be9a000 r--p 001b4000 08:02 395813                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f7b5be9a000-7f7b5be9c000 rw-p 001b8000 08:02 395813                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f7b5be9c000-7f7b5bea1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7b5bea1000-7f7b5c091000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3769                       /usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9.1
7f7b5c091000-7f7b5c290000 ---p 001f0000 08:02 3769                       /usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9.1
7f7b5c290000-7f7b5c295000 r--p 001ef000 08:02 3769                       /usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9.1
7f7b5c295000-7f7b5c299000 rw-p 001f4000 08:02 3769                       /usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9.1
7f7b5c299000-7f7b5c2b5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7b5c2b5000-7f7b5c2d7000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 396174                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f7b5c3c5000-7f7b5c4cb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7b5c4d0000-7f7b5c4d1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7b5c4d1000-7f7b5c4d2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7b5c4d2000-7f7b5c4d7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7b5c4d7000-7f7b5c4d8000 r--p 00022000 08:02 396174                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f7b5c4d8000-7f7b5c4da000 rw-p 00023000 08:02 396174                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fffbdfae000-7fffbdfcf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffbdfff000-7fffbe000000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]


[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```